# DatabaseError: The operation had to be aborted due to a network disconnect firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my android application to store the image urls liked by the user. But when the user likes the first image when the application is opened the image url is not stored in the firebase and logs:

> The operation had to be aborted due to a network disconnect firebase

When the user further likes the images it is properly stored in the firebase with no issues.

What could be the possible reason for this error?

Logs are:

```
08-26 11:35:16.703 23419-23419/prithvi.wallpaper:background_crash I/FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl: FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl created by ClassLoader com.google.android.chimera.container.internal.DelegateLastPathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/n/armeabi-v7a, /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/n/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]<br/>
08-26 11:35:16.704 23419-23419/prithvi.wallpaper:background_crash D/FirebaseCrashSenderServiceImpl: onCreate<br/>
08-26 11:35:17.449 23168-23168/prithvi.wallpaper I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:3<br/>
08-26 11:35:17.449 23168-23168/prithvi.wallpaper I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 3<br/>
08-26 11:35:19.036 23168-23483/prithvi.wallpaper W/RepoOperation: Transaction at /odKqVUDKv1TlRNmBFN9tXfeM3T93/liked_photos/-KQ4RxQkK7DHGYS8baD4 failed: DatabaseError: The operation had to be aborted due to a network disconnect<br/>
08-26 11:35:19.259 23168-23212/prithvi.wallpaper W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: I'm getting this error too (java admin sdk). Two years and it is still there? :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Firebase bug that is [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/u1mgEEODF-o). The Firebase engineer in the discussion said:

> It's related to doing a transaction before we get connected.  As a
>   workaround, you could listen to the ".info/connected" location in
>   Firebase, wait for it to become true (i.e. you are authenticated) and
>   then do the transaction.

The problem appears to still exist in version 9.4.0.

Comment: I'm getting this error too (java admin sdk). Two years and it is still there? :(